# Access vue data object from inside a forEach

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the below variable in my data:

```
 data: function () {
    return {
      myVariable: false,
    }
  }
```

How do I access this variable from with a looping function, like below?

```
  anArray.forEach(function(item) {
      this.myVariable = true; 
      // do something
  });
```

I get 'this' is undefinded as its looking in the current loop function, not the vuejs object.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use Arrow function so you don't create new scope within forEach loop and keep your `this` reference of your Vue component.

```
 anArray.forEach((item) => {
  this.myVariable = true; 
  // do something
});
```

Answer (score 9):

You could bind `this` to the scope of the function:

```
anArray.forEach(function(item) {
  this.myVariable = true; 
  // do something
}.bind(this));
```

Another is by using the arrow notation (I am not 100% sure):

```
anArray.forEach((item) => {
  this.myVariable = true; 
  // do something
});
```

Comment: Just to confirm, the second one will work fine. I prefer it personally as it's neater thank having `bind(this)` everywhere.